# ARKit, AnchorEntity, missing initialiser(s)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

Learning about the ARKit, I am watching all the AR WWDC content. In **Introducing ARKit 3**, where **RealityKit** is used for the first time, there is an example of using **AnchorEntity** with the 3rd **convenience** initializer from the first screenshot below.
[image: Xcode12.5iOS13]
Few of these initialisers are gone when a project is created in **Xcode 13 Beta** with the iOS15 target as on the screenshot below:
[image: Xcode13iOS15]
I looked up the documentation and found no extra information regarding this. Initialiser is available with no info on planned deprecation. I find it bizzare.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/anchorentity/3255326-init
What could be the reason for that? Can this be some sort of a bug related to beta xcode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no deprecation of the initialiser, you are building for the simulator.

When building for the simulator you don't get the same initialisers, as the simulator doesn't have the ARKit framework.

---

Change the target to a physical device or "Any iOS Device" and you should be fine.

Comment: Wow thank you, you saved me a lot of time. I can't remember other instances of methods being defined when building for a device but not in the simulator. 
Fascinating.